# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm trying to Import my DB into Workbench, but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near ''visa_santalucia' /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER
> SET utf8 */' at line 1

the 2 lines that have conflict are this ones:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'visa_santalucia' /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE 'visa_santalucia';
```

Both have a red line under visa_santalucia when I open the SQL editor, that tells me this is the error but I cannot find any way to import it.

Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Just remove the single quotes from around visa_santalucia in both occurrences and you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single quote 'visa_santalucia' with back-ticks like `visa_santalucia` which character you find on the top left row of your keyoard along with ~` key and see if it works.